# When to use () in a middleware and when to use just reference

Tags: express, middleware

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var cookieValidator = require('./cookieValidator')

var app = express()

async function validateCookies (req, res, next) {
  await cookieValidator(req.cookies)
  next()
}

app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(validateCookies)

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(400).send(err.message)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

In the above code both **cookieParser()** and **validateCookies** are middlewares but the way of executing them are different. There is a function like () with cookieParser but not with validateCookies. Can someone please explain why? Sorry If I am sounding foolish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app.use()` function takes a single parameter, which is a *function reference* for a function that serves as a middleware for your router in Express.

You’ve correctly included the reference to your `validateCookies` function without parenthesis, as you just want Express to know which function you’d like it to use as middleware, and not to execute it at the time (Express will invoke the function for you when it’s time).

`cookie-parser` is a bit of an outlier (and I can see from where your confusion stems). The `cookieParser()` function actually returns a function reference upon successful execution. This design is likely because this particular module allows developers to pass in certain values to change the resulting function’s behavior as a middleware.